# Where should I place certificate serial number in project?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, x509certificate, client-certificates

I have a project that pulls a security certificate from the sever, I am using the certificate serial number to grab at the one I need.

**My question is, where should I place the serial number in the project?**

- Should it be hardcoded in the app? (that does not seem right??)
- In    the config? (does not seem safe)

Also the serial number could change depending on environments, development or production.

What do enterprise level apps do in this case?
Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: A client app that talks to the server or a server app? Not quite clear from the question.

Comment: it's an app that pulls a certificate from the server its on and then uses the certificate to authenticate itself to a third party

Comment: So both the app and the cert are on the same server and you still feel it is not safe to have the number in the web.config. Is there a reason to not to feel safe?

Comment: Yes, it is best practice to encrypt connection strings in your web.config, so... I prefer not leaving serial number open, does not seen like something Facebook,Google, or Apple would do, I'm looking for enterprise level best practice

Comment: Not only connection strings can be encrypted but any part of the web.config file. But, still wonder how do you know google or facebook encrypt or not their server side stuff - we don't see it from the client side. And, the cert serial number does't seem like a first class secret, the private key should be.

Comment: Maybe they do, when I initially posted my question I was not aware you could encrypt any section in the config, so maybe they do put their cert serial number in the config. From my understanding of this post, serial number should be guarded as best as possible against attacks http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15690/how-does-adding-a-random-serial-number-improve-a-certificates-security

Comment: From what I understand, this comment Is about a scenario where the number is generated as an md5 hash. I am not convinced this is the case nowadays.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102088/discussion-between-sobbles-and-wiktor-zychla).

Answer (score 0):

Put the serial numbers to a dedicated Database table for instance **CertInformation** so they are stored safely. You can define the table having the fields:

1. Environment ("DEV","QA","PROD")
2. Certificate_number

then by the application you can perform a select on the DB and retrieve the wanted certificate number as:

```
select Certificate_number from CertInformation where Environment = '[target environment]'
```